# Basic ODE Question

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

ODEs is by far my weakest area so I thought to ask here.
Fix $a_1,\dots,a_d,b,x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^d$.
I'm trying to solve the *system*:
$$
\dot{x}_t = \left(\tanh(a \cdot x_t + b_1),\dots,\tanh(a \cdot x_t + b_d)
\right)
$$

**So Far:** *(What I've got)*

In that case I can solve
$$
\dot{x}_t = \tanh(ax_t +b) ; x_0=x_0.
$$
to be
$$
x_t = \frac{\log(\cosh(at +b))}{a} + c(x_0),
$$
where $c(x_0)$ is a constant depending on the initial condition $x_0$.

**Question:**
How can we solve the *multi-dimensional version*?  Unlike the 1-d version I don't know what do next.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Why the tag "lie-groups"? What do you mean with multi-dimensional version?

Comment: If $x$ is a d-dimensional vector (and so $\dot{x}$), why in the right hand side it seems that you have an n-dimensional vector?

Comment: I Fixed, thanks

Comment: So if you define $u=ax_t$, you get $\dot u=\sum_{j=1}^d a_j\tanh(u+b_j)$ which is still separable but does not look like having a simple anti-derivative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $d=1$.

You can solve it by using the fact that this ODE is "separable", namely 
$$
\frac{dx}{\tanh(a x +b) } = dt
$$
This gives you (integrate between $x_0$ and $x$ and between $0$ and $t$, then use $y = a x + b$)
$$
\int_{a x_0 + b}^{a x +b}\frac{dy}{\tanh(y) } = t
$$
The final step is to know that $1/\tanh(z) = \coth(z)$ and that $\int \coth(z) dz = \ln(\sinh(z))$. Now apply this fact to the above definite integral to obtain the solution.

EDIT:

For $d>1$, a strategy could be to use the scalar $z(t) = x(t) \cdot a$. Multiply by $a$ the RHS and LHS of the ODE system to obtain
$$
\dot{z}(t) = a_1 \tanh(z(t) +b_1)+...+ a_d \tanh(z(t) +b_d)
$$
with the initial condition $z(0) = a\cdot x_0$.
You still have a single ODE for $z$, but in general it seems difficult to find a general solution, unless $b_1 = ...= b_d$. If all the $b_i$ are the same, then you have the ODE:
$$
\dot{z}(t) = A \tanh(z(t) +B)
$$
with $A=a_1+...+a_d$ and $B=b_1,...,b_d$. This can be solved with a method analogous to the one shown for the $d=1$ case.

EDIT #2 (since I was asked):

For $d=1$ you have $x(t)=[\sinh^{-1}( e^{a t} \sinh(b+a x_0)) -b]/a$

For $d>1$ you have $z(t) = \sinh^{-1}(e^{A t} \sinh(B+z_0))-B$

Comment: I would be very curious to see how that solution would look explicitly (when B=0).

Comment: I updated the answer with your request, just put $B=0$ in the final formula.

Comment: Ah, and $z(t) = Ax(t)$?  So we just need A to be invertible to recover $x(t)$ in general?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean, $A$ is just a constant (a single number), like $a$, $b$, and $B$.

Comment: Oh, no,  $\cdot$ denoted the inner product and not the scalar action.  So A=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ should be a matrix...  I guess the solution won't work then...

Comment: The inner product is the scalar product (aka the "dot" product) if you are talking about Euclidean spaces. Still confused.

Comment: "Scalar action" is the group action of $\mathbb{R}$ on the vector space $\mathbb{R}^d$.